# How do I disable remote SSH login as root from a server?

Tags: server, root, remote-access, accounts

For security purposes my company wants me to not allow anyone to be able to log into our Ubuntu server as root remotely over SSH. We still want the root account to exist, we just do not want it to be able to be logged into remotely. How would I accomplish this?

Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I assume you meant logging in over SSH? Put the following line to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

If you want to deny certain users from logging in, put this in the configuration file:

```
DenyUsers root
```

This takes the blacklisting approach. Whitelisting is generally preferable. If your company needs to allow the `rob` and `admin` users log in on the server, use the following configuration directive:

```
AllowUsers rob admin
```

After making configuration file changes, restart the ssh service using the command:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

See also the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html).

Comment: and `sudo service ssh restart` to take effect

Comment: I don't see sshd_config file , I see this one /etc/ssh/ssh_config.

Comment: @ChinmayaB You have probably not installed the OpenSSH server. Try `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

Comment: It worth mentioning, that before disabling ssh for root user you need firstly configure ordinary user's ssh

Answer (score 16):

Edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, look for

```
PermitRootLogin
```

and set it to `no`.

Comment: If you do this without adding any users with `AllowUsers <username>` wouldn't this in effect allow no one to SSH in?

Comment: @JGlass You may be conflating this answer with the one above that has additional options - this specific line only bars root from logging in via SSH. If there are other users on the system, all other things being equal, they will still be able to login via SSH unless you `DenyUsers` those logins as well.

Comment: @armadadrive - ahh, thank you for the correction and explanation!

Answer (score 4):

The default configuration is for the root account to be locked so you can not log in as root remotely.  You don't have to do anything else, unless you also want to make sure that you can not log in as root remotely by using an RSA key.  Of course, if you don't want to do that, then just don't set up a root key.

Comment: That was not the default for my Linode Ubuntu 14.04 machine. `PermitRootLogin` was set to `yes` and there was no `AllowUsers` or `DenyUsers` config line. Unless I am missing something, I don't think it is safe to assume it is locked by default

Comment: @andrewtweber, root login is not prohibited via ssh config, but system wide by setting the root password to an invalid value that you can not enter.  Thus, as I said, you can still ssh in as root using an RSA key, just not with a password.

Comment: ok thanks, can you add that explanation to your answer and then I'll be able to remove my downvote

Comment: @andrewtweber, it's already in my answer..

Comment: your explanation of how the root account is locked is not in your answer. Anyways I can't remove a downvote unless your answer is edited, so go ahead and be stubborn about it if you want

Comment: This answer is terrible, it is assuming something that could be invalid, it isn't helping someone who wants to learn and it doesn't help someone if they actually need to manually lock root out. This is an non answer on the whole front.