# Unable to disable ssh root login

Tags: ssh, root

Unable to disable root login on Ubuntu 14.10

1. login as root
2. `vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config`
3. `PermitRootLogin` line is not here so i add it
4. `service ssh restart`
5. root login still works.

I even restarted the server and I'm still able to login in as root...
I also added a new user before i did all this.
Am I missing a step?

Comment: Here is a reference to similar question with specific examples: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27559/how-do-i-disable-remote-ssh-login-as-root-from-a-server

Answer (score 6):

`PermitRootLogin` is an `sshd` (the daemon) setting, not an `ssh` (the client) setting. It should go into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, where I'm reasonably certain you'll find a `PermitRootLogin` line.

Comment: Also remember to restart the `sshd` service.

Comment: The line in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` should be `PermitRootLogin no` , and no restart is necessary, at least on my system

Comment: @Serg again, wrong file, and a restart is required.

Comment: IIRC sshd will reread its configuration on HUP, though for most intents and purposes that amounts to a restart since it kills current connections.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to put this out there since on a normal iso install root account is disabled (unless maybe you enabled it)

I'm going to assume you didn't and you're using a cloud based service like maybe Digital Ocean, as they have root enabled unless you setup a key.

If this is the case, as I also use digital ocean, I find it is sometimes easier to allow root login, but restrict access by ip address.

In this way, if you're doing something where you definitely need root access, you can save some time by logging into root rather than your user account and then using sudo and having to put your password in again.

This is also done in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

At the bottom of the file add the line

```
AllowUsers root@youripaddress
```

Or if I'm way off base here and you enabled the root account you can also limit access by local address only.

```
AllowUsers root@192.168.1.100
```

Or you can allow any computer access on your LAN

```
AllowUsers root@192.168.1.x
```

If you do go this route, you may also want to define your regular user as well, cause I think if you setup AllowUsers and don't include that user it won't let you connect. So as an example, let's say you want to allow root access from xxx.xxx.x.xx, but allow user fer access from anywhere, the setting would look like

```
AllowUsers root@xxx.xxx.x.xx fer@*
```

`@*` means from anywhere

You can also `DenyUsers` much in the same way to prevent certain users ssh access.