# Someone is logged in to my private computer as root

Tags: login, security

Sometimes when I shot down I get this message:

```
Other users are logged in.
 - root (console)
```

Now, it's my private computer and no one is allowed to connect to it.

Has my security been compromised?
How can I prevent this?

Comment: is it you who have logged into root?   have you switched to a virtual-terminal and logged in, or opened a shell and `su` to became root; and your elevated session is what you're seeing as root?    I just looked at my system and `users` show me and root; I hit the ctrl-alt-f4 & yep there is my 'root'

Comment: Show the output of `w`. Yes, it's a one letter command.

Comment: @guiverc I didn't log into root and haven't switched to a virtual-terminal. When I use su in a terminal session it does not appear as a separate user when I use `users` or `w` in another terminal window.
@M.Dm. I guess you're asking for the output of `w` when I get the message on the question. I don't get it right now.

Comment: I'd suggest disabling remote 'root' login if it's enabled; forcing keyed entry only from remote (not passwords), and maybe watch your `/var/log/auth.log` file (note: cron and other jobs show in this file as well as users).   `tripwire` and other apps can monitor your system for changes which may be worth considering too

Comment: Thanks @guiverc for your reply. How do I disable remote root login?

Comment: have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/27559/how-do-i-disable-remote-ssh-login-as-root-from-a-server

Comment: Open a Terminal and type: 'w'. Is an entry shown for the 'root' account?