# Prohibiting remote login on Ubuntu 18

Tags: ssh, sshpass

I am trying to prevent remote access for my laptop.

I went into `sshd_config` to try and set it up.  My IT guy recommended the following changes to accomplish this:

```
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

However, when I went to make the changes the line of code says:

```
#PermitRootLogin prohibit
```

This seems like  a double negative.  so `yes` means prohibit and `no` means don't prohibit.  Can anyone confirm?

Comment: What do you mean ?   With the "when I went to make the changes the line of code says: #PermitRootLogin prohibit "

Comment: When I go into the the config file the line of code says:  


#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-no 
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* based releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based VMs (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases.  *There is no Ubuntu 18, the closest being Ubuntu Core 18*

Answer (score 0):

From:  [How do I disable remote SSH login as root from a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27559/how-do-i-disable-remote-ssh-login-as-root-from-a-server)

Put the following line to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

**PermitRootLogin no**

Afterwards; restart the service

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

EDIT:  **If you never going to use ssh what so ever, (like, never going to) why not disable it completely?**

```
sudo service ssh stop.
```

If you have it running.

Disable it too (If you never going to use it)

```
sudo systemctl disable ssh
```

Comment: So you are saying I should delete "prohibit" from the line?  
that is change "#PermitRootLogin prohibit-no" to "#PermitRootLogin -no"

Comment: Yes. It's kind of confusing I have to admit, but yes.

Comment: @JayBoyle I edited my answer, probably better now.  In case you *never* going to use ssh, you *can* disable it.

Comment: Very strange after I made your original suggested change and rebooted the system it did not recognize the wireless adapter.  i.e. I lost my internet connection

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please provide log/screenshot, this seems very strange indeed..

Comment: I just went back into the config file an reversed that. so now I am back on line.

I will try to disable the ssh now instead.

Comment: @JayBoyle Oh-  It was kind of confusing I thought you first had disabled ssh, or something else, anyway hope it gets solved,  //Regards.

Comment: Lines starting with a `#` sign are comments - the values shown there in the *original* config file just indicate the compiled-in defaults. AFAIK `prohibit-no` is not a valid value for the `PermitRootLogin` parameter (but it doesn't matter - since the line is commented out) and was probably created by someone editing the file previously.

Comment: Yeah; I assume @JayBoyle removed the # before saving the file, and tried it (hopefully)

Comment: OK just to circle back with @WilliamMartens 

1. I disable SSH per your instructions.

$ sudo systemctl disable ssh
And the final line on my terminal says 
"Removed /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service."

Then when I run a rkhunter the program says that ssh root access is still allowed.  How can that be?

Comment: @JayBoyle Oh, I have no idea, hope someone with expertise in this subject comes along and can explain; Sorry  & Hope it gets solved,  :/    //Best wishes